# CSS: How to target all elements within a given ID

Tags: css

Instead of doing the following to give a text color to all elements on the page:

```css
* {color: red;}
```

Is there a way to only apply it to all elements within a certain id? Something like this:

```css
#container * {color: red;}
```

Comment: Does `#container * { color: red; }` not work?!?

Comment: Ok, sorry, I must have been testing it wrong. My example did work. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Actually yes, exactly like you mentioned.

```css
#container * { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 5):

```css
#container * {color: red;}
```

Should work.

If you only want direct children to get the class, try

```css
#container>*{color: red;}
```

What browser are you using? (brand + version)

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought:

```css
#container * {color: red;}
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

For your example, can you use jQuery?

```
$('#container').children().css('color', 'red');
```

EDIT: I was indeed wrong, serves me right for trying to answer on my lunch break with half a sandwich in my hand -.-

Comment: Why would you use jQuery for this when simple CSS would do the trick?

Comment: Whyyyyyyyyyyy. http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif http://www.doxdesk.com/updates/2009.html#u20091116-zalgo

Comment: Not only that the use of jQuery is not needed. The answer is also wrong. The code above sets only the color of the direct children to red. The question was for all elements within a parent-element.

Answer (score -1):

We would be able to provide a much better solution if we were to see the HTML code as a reference.

What you are looking to do is use CSS selectors. ([CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

And it sounds like Attribute selectors may be an option for you. [Attribute Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors)

For example, the following attribute selector matches all H1 elements that specify the "title" attribute, whatever its value:

```
h1[title] { color: blue; }
```

In the following example, the selector matches all SPAN elements whose "class" attribute has exactly the value "example":

```
span[class=example] { color: blue; }
```

Comment: @Domenic what about the above answer do you have a question about?

Comment: What does it have to do with the question?

Comment: He asked how to give a certain color to specific elements on a page. Those are called CSS selectors (provided a link) and I also gave him additional information on what's called an Attribute selector (provided a link) if he wanted to match elements of a specific class. Why class? Because he used the term 'ID' wrong in his question, there aren't multiple IDs on a page, only 1. There can be multiple classes. That's why.

Comment: "Is there a way to only apply it to all elements **within** a certain id?" Also... using the attribute selector instead of the class selector for classes is wrong in more ways than I can count.

Comment: :) best of. Defending the own confuse answer with the reason that another answer is more wrong. Nearly +1 for that

Comment: @domenic You got me on *within*. But the attribute selector is definitely not wrong - it's a more specific way to identify elements on the page that you want to modify through CSS. And it's used for more than just class, any attribute can be used I only provided the example from W3C's site.

Comment: Yes... but using the attribute selector for **classes** is very, very wrong. I'll give you a hint why: `<span class="bar example foo">stuff</span>`.